# How did the Mario Brothers discover/enter the Mushroom Kingdom?

Tags: video-games, super-mario-brothers

The Mario Brothers are described as Italian brothers who are plumbers, not native inhabitants of the Mushroom Kingdom.

How did the Mario Brothers first discover and enter the Mushroom Kingdom?

For purposes of this question, the live-action movie is not canon.

Comment: I feel like this question is based on the misguided notion that there is a strong sense of canon behind the "story" of the Mario games...

Comment: I panicked, until I saw the last sentence.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hOqLNn-C6c0 - "found the secret warp-zone by working on the drain" ;D

Comment: @DrRDizzle most game creators come up with even just a loose backstory. a comment about that would be perfectly fine here.

Comment: @phantom42 The problem here is that the loose backstory is just "Mario is an Italian plumber/carpenter who lives in the Mushroom Kingdom". There is no explanation for how he got to the Mushroom Kingdom, if he comes from our Italy or the Mushroom Kingdoms version of Italy etc because every aspect of his character comes from a design perspective, not a story one. Mario just *is*.

Comment: Besides @DrRDizzle's point, it's also important to note that early Nintendo English-language promotional materials were generally improvised for the American market, not created under consultation with Nintendo in Japan. For instance, there's nothing about where Mario came from in the early game manuals, and anything outside of that context in English would certainly not come from the games' creators.

Comment: in super mario world, mario wakes up in the mushroom kingdom i believe unsure of where he is.

Comment: Would you accept the Super Mario Bros Super Show cartoon as canon? It says they got there after trying to unclot a toilet, or something...that's what I remember from the show intro...

Comment: Broader question, how did *ANY* humans find the mushroom kingdom. It seems they *do* exist there since a human (Peach) is their ruler..

Comment: @Skooba till peach isnt a human and her lady bits are a mystery?!

Comment: Are you interested only in SMB(1) for the NES or would you be willing to look at answers from later games where the plot is far more developed?

Comment: @tilley31 ideally, games - but if it's all we've got, i'd consider it - particularly if there's any word from nintendo to give it weight

Comment: @Valorum perfect world, i'd love a S/MB explanation if one exists. if not, one from the other games would be acceptable

Comment: @DrRDizzle "Mario just is" .... and here we have a resemblace with Tom Bombadil!

Comment: @Francesco i don't remember the colors in the English limerick for Bombadil, but i remember the French ones,and Mario's color scheme is off there :p

Comment: Hmm, and then they got into Mario Cart world....

Comment: Is the new movie considered canon?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It would seem that any origin plot, if any, can only be derived from cross-referencing the various games.

As Valorum already said, the original NES/Famicom *Super Mario Bros.* game didn't provide many details - we just know that Mario set out to save the Mushroom Kingdom and Princess ---Toadstool--- Peach, but we don't really know were he came from.

This plot point - Mario's origin - wasn't touched upon in the main games for a while, so for the time being the only possible answers were to be drawn from the related material such as the comics, the animated shows, Choose Your Own Adventure game books, and so on.
Most of this related material seems to indicate that the Mushroom Kingdom is intended to be a different dimension and Mario arrived there using a warp pipe (see above comments about the animated show. It not only specifies that Mario and Luigi found an entrance to the Mushroom Kingdom while performing some plumbing job, but it also shows Bowser trying to use the pipes to launch an attack on the human world multiple times).

This is somewhat consistent with the games in a way: even before the *Super Mario Bros.* game, Mario appeared in another game, called just *Mario Bros.* (even before he appeared in other games as well, *Donkey Kong* being just one example, albeit the character wasn't always called Mario in those). In that game, Mario is "fighting enemies he came across while performing his job as a plumber" (will try to find an actual transcript/screenshot of the original manual), so while there is no official **in-game** reference that I know of, it seems plausible that in the original NES-era Mario was indeed intended to be an Italian plumber (possibly living in America) who came to the Mushroom Kingdom  using a warp pipe he found "sometime, somewhere".

This is somewhat confirmed by some old Miyamoto claims/interview where he says [he had Mario live in New York and that he gave him an Italian origin because of his mustache](http://content.usatoday.com/communities/gamehunters/post/2010/11/qa-mario-creator-shigeru-miyamoto/1).

Then the SNES came out, and we got *Yoshi's Island*. In this game, we control Yoshi, who is trying to bring a baby version Mario (and baby Luigi, who was kidnapped by Kamek) back to his parents-to-be, after a stork "lost"  them due to being attacked by Kamek. This seems to indicate that "baby" Mario was born in the Mushroom Kingdom - the game ending even shows him being delivered to a house... and while I may be mistaken, that doesn't exactly look like Italy.

[image]

(*Notice: on the left, the original storyboard for the SNES game ending. On the right, the same clip, taken from the DS remake "Yoshi's New Island" instead.*)

Later still, the plot only gets cloudier. Games like "Mario & Luigi: Partners in Time" seem to confirm that the "baby Mario" timeline is the same as the adult Mario one, but even later games throw in another curve ball, as we discover that the world seen in the *Paper Mario* series is not just a different art style for the same world, but actually another dimension altogether (*Mario & Luigi: Paper Jam*).

I would assume that, right now, the only real clue as to the original intent seems to derive from the first games (and was actually somehow reused in a very unlucky movie...), as I fear that no more thought has ever been put into this. After all, they only relinked the *Zelda* franchise years after the original games were made, so I fear that hoping for an official source on Mario's origin within a game may be a lost cause.

Comment: I was hoping for a tie-in to MLP somehow.

Comment: @amaranth Well, there are two Mario and Luigi ponies in the comics, and Link was in the background during S06E11...

Comment: *first game to actually use the name "Mario" for the main character is actually Mario Bros* --- I read that the first game to use the name Mario was the English artwork for the Donkey Kong cabnet.

Comment: I was just coming to say the same thing @JDługosz - The "Mario is from another dimension" idea comes from the movie and the tv show I'd wager. There is nothing in the game to make us think that. The original game "Mario Bros" was pipes and mushroom kingdom-esque characters. Super Mario Bros has the Mushroom Kingdom littered with pipes - wouldn't it make sense that there would be native plumbers? Where in the manual / source material are we told Mario is 'Italian'?

Comment: "baby Mario a stark lost" Is nothing sacred, GRRM?!

Comment: @NKCampbell - obviously, the country name "Italy" is never used in the actual games (unless maybe in some trophies description in the Smash Bros franchise). The only official sources are declarations/interviews from the game creators themselves and the occasional Italian words Mario often uses (*"Mammamia*" comes to mind)

Comment: It's an Italian name. The Donkey Kong wikipedia page says how the DK character was designed for practical reasons, and the Amaricans re-named it from (Japanese for) Jumpman to Mario when doing the cabinet art, because he looked like someone they knew named Mario.

Answer (score 47):

The [original backstory](http://legendsoflocalization.com/media/super-mario-bros/manuals/Super-Mario-Bros-Manual-US.pdf) for Super Mario Bros is laughably short. Mario heard that the Mushroom Kingdom was in danger and set out on a quest to free it. No information is given about his mode of transport to the Kingdom, nor whether he lives in the magical world normally or traveled there from the human world.

> **OBJECT OF THE GAME/GAME DESCRIPTION**
>
> One day the kingdom of the peaceful mushroom people was invaded by the
>   Koopa, a tribe of turtles famous for their black magic. The quiet, peace-loving
>   Mushroom People were turned into mere stones, bricks and even field horse-hair plants, and the Mushroom Kingdom fell into ruin.
>   The only one who can undo the magic spell on the Mushroom People and
>   return them to their normal selves is the Princess Toadstool, the daughter of
>   the Mushroom King. Unfortunately, she is presently in the hands of the great
>   Koopa turtle king.
>
> Mario, the hero of the story (maybe) hears about the Mushroom People's
>   plight and sets out on a quest to free the Mushroom Princess from the evil
>   Koopa and restore the fallen kingdom of the Mushroom People.
>
> You are Mario! It's up to you to save the Mushroom People from the black
>   magic of the Koopa!

[image]

The [Game & Watch](http://www.replacementdocs.com/request.php?2958) version manual features a backstory that is even more terse (but undeniably cooler due to the inclusion of funky pictures)

[image]

Comment: For reference - [SMB2](http://www.mariomayhem.com/downloads/mario_instruction_booklets/Super_Mario_Bros_2-NES.pdf) and [SMB3](http://www.mariomayhem.com/downloads/mario_instruction_booklets/smb3_nes_manual.pdf)

Comment: Oh wow - ambiguity in that first game. Mario is the hero....maybe? What is that all about?! :)

Comment: @NKCampbell - see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BIePWBgKaXw

Comment: So, the short answer is, Why does it need an in-depth backstory? :-)

Comment: @jpaugh - Hells yeah. I've played entire FPS games with the sound off, scrolling through the dialogue at hyper-speed and never noticed a darn thing. I don't need a plotline in my games any more than I need a plotline in my breakfast cereal.

Comment: I need a plotline in my breakfast cereal!! :-)

Comment: @jpaugh - Once upon a time, there was a tiger named Tony. And he was Grrreat! The End.

Comment: @NKCampbell "From my perspective the mushroom kingdom is evil!"

Comment: `turned into bricks` - so Mario is killing members of the Mushroom Kingdom, and the coins are probably just whatever they had in their pockets. Man, that game turned dark quickly.

Comment: *Mario, the hero of the story, hears about the Mushroom People's plight and sets out on a quest to free the Mushroom Princess from the evil Koopa and restore the fallen kingdom of the Mushroom People.*

You are Luigi. It's up to you to sit around, watch Netflix, and smoke Mario's stash of Fire Flowers.

Comment: @WayneWerner The lore is he's transforming them back and they give him coins as thanks

Comment: The reason it says Mario is "the hero (maybe)" is to emphasize that he will only be the hero if he succeeds in his quest.  Most versions of the story are tragedies ending in "GAME OVER."

Answer (score 1):

### They lived there.

The [manual for the Super Mario Bros Deluxe (GBC)](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/gbc/198850-super-mario-bros-deluxe/faqs/7415) adds in some more detail:

> Once upon a time, the peaceful Mushroom Kingdom was invaded by the Koopa, a tribe of turtles famous for their dark magic. These terrible terrapins transformed the peace-loving Mushroom People into stones, bricks, and ironically, mushrooms then set their own evil king on the throne. In the wake of the ghastly coup d'etat, the beautiful Mushroom Kingdom fell into ruin and despair.
>
> It is said that only the daughter of the Mushroom King, Princess
> Toadstool, can break the evil spell and return the inhabitants of the Mushroom Kingdom to their normal selves.
>
> But the King of the Koopas, knowing of this prophecy, kidnapped the lovely Princess and hid her away in one of his castles.
>
> **Word of the terrible plight of the Mushroom People quickly spread throughout the land, eventually reaching the ears of a humble plumber.** The simple, yet valiant Mario vowed to rescue the Princess from King Koopa's tyrannous reign. But can Mario really overcome the many obstacles facing him and become a true hero?

The line in bold implies they lived there.

Comment: No it doesn't. If he lived in the Mushroom Kingdom he'd know immediately that it was being invaded. Not have to wait for word of the ruined kingdom to reach him.

Comment: That's not true. There's no real communication systems.

Comment: makes sense with all those pipes that there would be plumbers hanging out

Comment: @TheAsh - When Biden does or says something dumb, word if it spreads throughout the land and eventually I hear about it, despite not living in America.